# IB API placing combo order fails - No security definition has been found for the request

Tags: java, interactive-brokers

What's wrong with the following order? I can request the contract id's but cannot place the order (Facebook Iron Condor)

```
23:00:48:360 <- 9-7-20-0-FB-OPT-20151218-110.0-C-100-CBOE-USD---0---

23:00:48:371 <- 9-7-21-0-FB-OPT-20151218-105.0-C-100-CBOE-USD---0---

23:00:48:375 <- 9-7-22-0-FB-OPT-20151218-92.5-P-100-CBOE-USD---0---

23:00:48:380 <- 9-7-23-0-FB-OPT-20151218-97.5-P-100-CBOE-USD---0---

23:00:49:299 -> 10-8-20-FB-OPT-20151218-110-C-CBOE-USD-FB    151218C00110000-FB-FB-190969025-0.01-100-[rest deleted]

23:00:49:300 -> 52-1-20-

23:00:49:328 -> 10-8-21-FB-OPT-20151218-105-C-CBOE-USD-FB    151218C00105000-FB-FB-190969020-0.01-100-[rest deleted]

23:00:49:328 -> 52-1-21-

23:00:49:357 -> 10-8-22-FB-OPT-20151218-92.5-P-CBOE-USD-FB    151218P00092500-FB-FB-191896815-0.01-100-[rest deleted]

23:00:49:357 -> 52-1-22-

23:00:49:385 -> 10-8-23-FB-OPT-20151218-97.5-P-CBOE-USD-FB    151218P00097500-FB-FB-199892805-0.01-100-[rest deleted]

23:00:49:386 -> 52-1-23-

23:00:49:574 <- 3-43-24-0-USD-BAG--0.0---CBOE--USD-----BUY-1-MKT------O-0--1-0-0-0-0-0-0-0-4-190969025-1-BUY-CBOE-0-0---1-190969020-1-SELL-CBOE-0-0---1-191896815-1-BUY-CBOE-0-0---1-199892805-1-SELL-CBOE-0-0---1-0-0--0.0-------0---1-0---0---0-0--0------0-----0-----------0---0-0---0--

23:00:49:883 -> 4-2-24-200-No security definition has been found for the request-
```

Answer (score 0):

First I'll explain the solution to that error message when I came across it, then I'll list other possible solutions to the problem.

I've seen that error for several different reasons when researching it, but in my case using options, it was because:

**- The specific contract I was requesting didn't currently exist on the market.**

The option contract I requested didn't exist yet at the strike I wanted to use because it was somewhat far out from expiry, where some strikes often don't exist yet.

For example at that specific expiry, if one option strike is 100, then the next closest existing contracts might only have strikes of 95 and 105, rather than contracts existing for all strikes 95, 96, 97 , 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, and 105.

I was trying to use request data for contracts with strikes 95 - 105, so it was acting correctly for the 3 strikes that actually existed ( 95, 100, 105), but for the rest of the strikes inbetween, it was giving me your same error "no security definition found for request".

**Other** possible reasons for the error that I came across include:

- the ConId should be left at 0.
- the TradingClass should be left blank.
- Issues with the LocalSymbol or GlobalSymbol
- Other Contract variables were incorrectly set